# Stopping @spawn-ed tasks in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, task, julia

I'm in the following situation: an algorithm from a library uses some randomness, and usually is very fast but sometimes gets stuck (this is common for SAT solvers, e.g.).

I would like to do the following: start many instances of the task, and keep the result of the first one succeeding, killing the others. In Julia pseudocode:

```
futures = [@spawn myfunction(mydata)]
while true
    i = findnext(isready, futures)
    if i != nothing
        result = fetch(i)
        foreach(kill_task, futures)
        break
    end
    sleep(0.1)
end
```

but I can't find anything like "kill_task"; `Distributed.del_client` sounded like a good possibility, but doesn't seem to do that.

As a bonus, it would be nice to avoid the polling (sleeps etc.)

Note that it's not acceptable to modify "myfunction" to ask it to die itself, it has to be killed (since it's in an external library).

Comment: OK, partial answer to my first question: "isready" says if a future has its output ready.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete code that spawns several worker processes, gets the result from the one that completed sooner and once the result is received all workers get terminated.
I think this code is very useful for many scenarios is scientific computing:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using Distributed 

@everywhere function getSomething()
   tt = rand(1:20)
   println("working for $tt seconds")
   for i in 1:tt
       sleep(1.0)
   end
   println("Finally, I am ready")
   return 100+myid()
end

function getFirst(workerf::Function, ws_list::Vector{Int}=workers())
    res = Vector{Union{Future,Nothing}}(nothing,length(ws_list))
    for i in 1:length(ws_list)
        @async begin
        res[i] = @spawnat ws_list[i] workerf()
        end        
    end
    my_res = nothing
    while true       
        for i in 1:length(ws_list)
            if res[i]!=nothing && isready(res[i]) 
                my_res = fetch(res[i])
                println(ws_list[i]," is ready!")
                break
            else
                println(ws_list[i]," NOT ready!")
            end 
        end
        if my_res != nothing
            @sync for i in 1:length(ws_list)
                @async interrupt(ws_list[i])
            end
            break
        end
        sleep(0.5)
    end
    println(my_res)
    return my_res
end
```

Now let us give it a spin:

```
julia> value = getFirst(getSomething);
2 NOT ready!
      From worker 4:    working for 16 seconds
      From worker 2:    working for 19 seconds
      From worker 5:    working for 2 seconds
3 NOT ready!
      From worker 3:    working for 15 seconds
4 NOT ready!
5 NOT ready!
2 NOT ready!
3 NOT ready!
4 NOT ready!
5 NOT ready!
2 NOT ready!
3 NOT ready!
4 NOT ready!
5 NOT ready!
2 NOT ready!
3 NOT ready!
4 NOT ready!
5 NOT ready!
      From worker 5:    Finally, I am ready
2 NOT ready!
3 NOT ready!
4 NOT ready!
5 is ready!
Worker 3 terminated.
Worker 2 terminated.
Worker 5 terminated.
Worker 4 terminated.
```

And let us see the result:

```
julia> println(value)
105
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
However, it seems there's a race condition if another worker finished before the interrupt() call: in that case, the whole Julia kernel gets killed on that worker.

Comment: The documentation for `interrupt` reads "Interrupt the current executing task on the specified workers. This is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-C   on the local machine".". Normally, in many cases, pressing Ctrl-C on REPL kills the Julia kernell process in an ugly way. Hence I would say that once you call interrupt on a worker a process can be dead or not - you might want to check their state.